# How to incorporate javascript with HTML to make table change color depending on value?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I create a javascript that will change the color of the box depending on it's value?

```
<table>
<tr class="top row">
    <th> Status </th>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th> StudentID </th>
    <th> Grades </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> BAD </td>
    <td> Jason </td>
    <td> 955012 </td>
    <td> 20 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

eg; if box value (td) = OK box will be green, if value is BAD box will be yellow.

**Current Java script based from similar question**

```
 $('#test [id^="available_"]').each(function(){

var closestTd = $(this).closest('td');
var valueCache = parseInt($(this).val());

if(valueCache === CRITICAL) {
   closestTd .addClass('red');
}
else if(valueCache === BAD) {
   closestTd.addClass('yellow');
}
else {
   closestTd.addClass('green');
}

});
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so we can point you in the right direction!

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery? This would be a perfect situation to use it.

Comment: How are you generating the HTML table code? If using PHP you could change the color then.

Comment: @kamigoosby I never used Jquery, I wouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: @jc__ It's a plain html file, linked with a css and a js file.

Comment: @Jite I am trying if else statements with js. But I do not know how to specify that one cell.

Comment: Can you add an attribute with status code like this, `<td data-status="0"> BAD </td>`, to your element? ... as reading the text is a bad solution. What if you want to say why it is bad .. or a second language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution using JS.

Here is a function which applies a unique class to each td which has a value that you specified.

```
function addTdClass(string) {
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    var str = element[i].innerHTML;
    if (str.indexOf(string) !== -1) {
      element[i].className = 'td-' + string;
    }
  };  
}

addTdClass('BAD');
```

Live Example
http://codepen.io/KarlDoyle/pen/kkxqbv

Comment: @Jesse - No problem, if your have some flexibility with your code, i would suggest the css method I highlighted below :)

Comment: I may have implemented your code below wrong or something, It didn't work for me earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do this with pure CSS.

Notice the `data-status` attribute with the value

```
<table>
<tr class="top row">
    <th> Status </th>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th> StudentID </th>
    <th> Grades </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td data-status="BAD"> BAD </td>
    <td> Jason </td>
    <td> 955012 </td>
    <td> 20 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS for styling

```
tr td[data-status="OK"] {
  background-color: green;
}
tr td[data-status="BAD"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Example
http://codepen.io/KarlDoyle/pen/jraJEB

Comment: Change `<td alt="BAD">` to `<td data-status="BAD">` and you'll get an upvote from me

Comment: @LGSon - I actually had that initially :)

Comment: Now what if the value "BAD" turns to "OK". Is this basically changing the cell color based on the value? @KarlDoyle

Comment: @Jesse, if the value "BAD" turns to "OK" then cell's background becomes "yellow"

Comment: @Jesse - Agreed as mentioned by denysM. The idea is that if you are generating the values, then you can generate the attribute value also

Answer (score 2):

Give some class name to each td where you want to apply check on value based ie
Use below code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if($(".chkval").text()=="OK"){
      $(".chkval").css("background-color","green");
}
else if($(".chkval").text()=="BAD"){
      $(".chkval").css("background-color","yellow");
}
});


    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
<tr class="top row">
    <th> Status </th>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th> StudentID </th>
    <th> Grades </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="chkval"> BAD </td>
    <td> Jason </td>
    <td> 955012 </td>
    <td> 20 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it dorsn't work. please, read [doc](http://api.jquery.com/html/), you need to use .text() instead.

Comment: @DenysM thanks for correction.i have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `innerHTML` to get value from `td`:

```
<table>
<tr class="top row">
    <th> Status </th>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th> StudentID </th>
    <th> Grades </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="td"> OK </td>
    <td> Jason </td>
    <td> 955012 </td>
    <td> 20 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="path/to/your/script.js"></script>
```

script.js:

```
   var td = document.getElementById('td');
   if(td.innerHTML == ' OK ')
      td.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
   else if(td.innerHTML == ' BAD ')
      td.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

**EDIT**: added JS function `trim()`:

```
    var td = document.getElementById('td');
    if(td.innerHTML.trim() == 'OK')
        td.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    else if(td.innerHTML.trim() == 'BAD')
        td.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

Comment: Is it possible to put that script in a external js file?. Thank you, Would I have to create more than one ID for each box? Currently it's only coloring 1 cell.

Comment: @Jesse Reading the text is a bad solution. What if you want to say why it is bad .. or a second language .. or in this case, the space chars get trimmed on one or the other?

Comment: @DenysM - There are various issues with this approach, primarily, if you have multiple TD's with the same value. and your required to apply an ID to each which is quite heavy

Comment: @Karl, I agree with you. I just want to show example using Jesse's html code. As for me, more easier to use jQuery. But Jesse said that he never used jQuery. Also we can use JS function trim() and remove whitespace from both sides of a string.

Comment: If you have multiple TD's and you want to check its value that time you can use class attribute as I have shown in my code